# Removing dead space from a report if a sub-report is hidden

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Unfortunately my company won't allow uploads so I can't show you, but I'll try to explain it.  I've got a report made up of 30 or so sub-reports.  Each sub-report is laid out in succession, one grid space below the other.  They each take up the full width of the report.

With this report, the user can select which sub-reports they want to see.  So, I've set all the sub-reports' Visible property to False, and when the report loads I determine if they should be displayed or not.  The problem is, if the user selects, say, the 14th, 15th and 16th sub-reports, there's a bunch of dead space above it.  I've got all of them set so Can Grow and Can Shrink are True.  Is there any way to eliminate the dead space taken up by a sub-report?

Comment: A screenshot of design view would really help... Is there empty space *between* the subreports? Reduce that to a minimum (like 0.1 mm).

Comment: In addition to Andre's suggestion, I would remove ALL spacing between subreports, but then build the needed spacing into the header and/or footer of the subreports. Thus if hidden, should not be an issue.

Comment: Double check the CanGrow/CanShrink properties on the report section properties as well (Detail/Header) it's easy to miss.